# Installed nginx on ubuntu server, still seeing apache2 default screen

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-server

I installed nginx on ubuntu server 16.10, and it appeared to work fine, When I accessed the machine, I got the the default nginx welcome page. "Welcome to nginx"...

I did't work with the machine for 2 days, but when I accessed it today, I got the Ubuntu Apache2 Default Screen.

Why is it acting like that ?

Answer (score 0):

which port no you have given for apache as well as for nginx if both are same try to change port no of apache, and try again once.

Basically both are http web server so they will listen on port 80(default).

or else try to remove or uninstall apache from you system.

Thank you